# How to solve this converter Hexadecimal to octal like excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to convert Hexadecimal to octal like excel in C#.

In normal converter:

```
=Hex2Oct("FFF0FFFFFF") 
Answer:17776077777777
```

In Excel:

```
=Hex2Oct("FFF0FFFFFF") 
Answer:6077777777
```

How could I solve this problem
Is anyone Know please suggest me?

Comment: The Excel response is wrong. It is truncating.

Answer (score 0):

Excel *truncates* the result so it's incorrect; according to the manual

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-nz/article/HEX2OCT-function-d52055af-1be5-43c1-9319-2ce0ab3569f4

```
- If number is negative, it cannot be less than FFE0000000, 
  and if number is positive, it cannot be greater than 1FFFFFFF.
```

...

so your argument ("FFF0FFFFFF") is out of range.

Sample C# code

```
private static String Hex2Oct(String value) {
  // Assuming that given value is short enough to be represented as Int64
  return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(value, 16), 8);
}
...
Console.Write(Hex2Oct("FFF0FFFFFF")); // 17776077777777
```